# Hibernate org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, entity

I'm doing this in Spring, new to JPQL. What exactly I'm doing wrong with the query (It's in CustomerOrder class)? Tried to do it in a couple of ways but I always get that exception down there. When I try @NamedNativeQuery and query in through a REST endpoint I get a grammar exception.

The second thing is that I'm using spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto, can this be the case and the tables should be created manually?

This is the first class. It's @OneToMany relationship

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Long customerId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "telephone")
    private Long telephone;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<CustomerOrder> orderList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, Long telephone, String email, Address address) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = new Address(address);
    }
```

This is the second part of the relationship

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_order")
@NamedQuery(query =
        "SELECT c.customerId, " +
                "c.firstName, " +
                "c.lastName," +
                " c.telephone, " +
                "c.email, " +
                "c.address.country," +
        " c.address.houseNumber, " +
                "c.address.apartmentNumber, " +
                "c.address.postalCode," +
                " c.address.postalCode, " +
        "o.orderId, " +
                "o.totalPrice, " +
                " o.totalQuantity, " +
                "o.cartItems " +
        "FROM CustomerOrder o JOIN o.customer c", name = "Order.query")
public class CustomerOrder implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private Long orderId;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "cart_items", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"))
    private List<CartItem> cartItems;

    @Column(name = "total_price")
    private BigDecimal totalPrice;

    @Column(name = "total_quantity")
    private Integer totalQuantity;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    public CustomerOrder() {
    }

    public CustomerOrder(List<CartItem> items , CustomerOrderRequest request) {
        this.cartItems = new LinkedList<>(items);
        this.totalPrice = request.getTotalPrice();
        this.totalQuantity = request.getTotalQuantity();
    }
```

Repository:

```
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface CustomerOrderRepository extends CrudRepository<CustomerOrder, Long> {


    @Query(name = "Order.query")
    List<FullOrder> findALlOrders();
}
```

And this is the class all the data should be mapped to.

```
public class FullOrder {
    private Long customerId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Long telephone;
    private String email;
    private String country;
    private Integer houseNumber;
    private Integer apartmentNumber;
    private String postalCode;
    private String city;
    private Long orderId;
    private BigDecimal totalPrice;
    private Integer totalQuantity;
    private List<CartItem> cartItems;
 
const. getters setters etc.
```

The Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository' defined in luke.shopbackend.repository.RoleRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
Order.query failed because of: org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity [SELECT c.customerId, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.telephone, c.email, c.address.country, c.address.houseNumber, c.address.apartmentNumber, c.address.postalCode, c.address.postalCode, o.orderId, o.totalPrice,  o.totalQuantity, o.cartItems FROM luke.shopbackend.model.entity.CustomerOrder o JOIN o.customer c]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:621) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at luke.shopbackend.ShopBackendApplication.main(ShopBackendApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
Order.query failed because of: org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity [SELECT c.customerId, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.telephone, c.email, c.address.country, c.address.houseNumber, c.address.apartmentNumber, c.address.postalCode, c.address.postalCode, o.orderId, o.totalPrice,  o.totalQuantity, o.cartItems FROM luke.shopbackend.model.entity.CustomerOrder o JOIN o.customer c]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
Order.query failed because of: org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity [SELECT c.customerId, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.telephone, c.email, c.address.country, c.address.houseNumber, c.address.apartmentNumber, c.address.postalCode, c.address.postalCode, o.orderId, o.totalPrice,  o.totalQuantity, o.cartItems FROM luke.shopbackend.model.entity.CustomerOrder o JOIN o.customer c]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
Order.query failed because of: org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity [SELECT c.customerId, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.telephone, c.email, c.address.country, c.address.houseNumber, c.address.apartmentNumber, c.address.postalCode, c.address.postalCode, o.orderId, o.totalPrice,  o.totalQuantity, o.cartItems FROM luke.shopbackend.model.entity.CustomerOrder o JOIN o.customer c]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You don't need custom query. All information in `FullOrder` is already in `CustomerOrder` just use `findAll` on `CustomerOrderRepository`. If you really need that `FullOrder` instance you can create it and fill with info from `CustomerOrder`.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is I got inf. recursion and StackOverflow: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError). So I passed @JsonBackReference and Managed Reference. And now it doesn't send a full object.

Comment: That problem with stack overflow is easier to fix then one you created :) I'd probably just put `@JsonIgnore` on `orderList`.

Comment: Thanks, ill try that a little later. I did this way cause someone wrote that it's better than JsonIgnore. Will see

Comment: You did it. Now everything works smooth and life is better. If you post that comment with the change to @JsonIgnore ill accept it for an answer. Thanks

Comment: It answers different question. You better accept Oleh Kurpiak answer, because it answers question your posted. Kind of.

Comment: Sound fine. Still i think i could upvote yours. But dont have 15 rep yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it you want to bind you custom select result to your non entity object then you have to do something like this

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
class FullOrder {
   private Long orderId;
   private BigDecimal totalPrice;
}


@Repository
public interface CustomerOrderRepository extends CrudRepository<CustomerOrder, Long> {

    @Query(query = "select new full.path.to.class.FullOrder(c.orderId, c.totalPrice) from CustomeOrder c")
    List<FullOrder> findALlOrders();
}
```

Spring Data will invoke constuctor of `FullOrder` so property order & property type if matter